# How to can I pass data from a host fragment to dialog fragment in kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a RecylcerView that the view is clicked should take the user to a dialog fragment where the user will be able to edit the content of the view. Hence i need to pass the data as data class DressMeasurementModel from the host fragment to the dailog fragment.

How can i achieve this?

```
    // This property is only valid between onCreateView and onDestroyView.
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var addMeasurementFab: FloatingActionButton
    private lateinit var display:TextView
    private lateinit var myAdapter: AddMeasurementAdapter
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = MeasurementsFragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)


        val recyclerView = binding.measurementsFragmentRecyclerView
        myAdapter = AddMeasurementAdapter(currentList,this@MeasurementsFragment, this@MeasurementsFragment)
        recyclerView.adapter = myAdapter
        recyclerView.layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
    }

    override fun onItemClicked1(dressMeasurementModel: DressMeasurementModel) {
        val data = DressMeasurementModel(dressMeasurementModel.measurementName, dressMeasurementModel.measurement)
        val bundle = bundleOf("editData" to data)
        setFragmentResult("editData_key", bundle)
        EditMeasurementDialogFragment().show(childFragmentManager, "Dialog tag")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have your Dialog class with a constructor which you want the data:

```
class EditMeasurementDialogFragment(data: DressMeasurementModel)
```

You can pass it in a constructor like below:

```
 val data = DressMeasurementModel(dressMeasurementModel.measurementName, dressMeasurementModel.measurement)
EditMeasurementDialogFragment(data).show(childFragmentManager, "Dialog tag")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
add this into your dialog fragment

    companion object {

    private const val ITEMS = "data"

    fun newInstance(data : DressMeasurementModel): EditMeasurementDialogFragment= EditMeasurementDialogFragment().apply {
        arguments = Bundle().apply {
            putString(ITEMS, Gson().toJson(data))
        }
    }
}
```

And call this fragment dialog from your fragment

```
     val dialog = EditMeasurementDialogFragment.newInstance(items)
     dialog.show(childFragmentManager, "dialog")
```

// get argument into your dialog fragment on Start or on create

```
  val data = argument?.getString(ITEMS)
  val model = Gson().fromJson(data,DressMeasurementModel::class.java)
```

// or you can simple pass model or data into primary construct like

```
     class EditMeasurementDialogFragment(data: DressMeasurementModel)
```